# Adding a rollover only works on one image div

Tags: html, css

I am creating a rollover on an image div where once you roll over, the image opacity goes down and text over the top appears. This works fine for just one image, but when trying it on more then one image the opacity doesn't work correctly and the text doesn't seem to appear on the other images.

HTML:

```
 <div class="worklongdiv" style="padding-top:111px";>
    <img src="images/Vividworklong.jpg"/>
    <div class="work-text-content-long">
      <header>VIVID VAPOURS</header>
      <p style="font-size:17px; font-family:GothamRoundedBold;">Branding • Product Dev • Web Dev</p>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="worklongdiv" >
    <img src="images/Vividworklong.jpg"/>
    <div class="work-text-content-long">
      <header>VIVID VAPOURS</header>
      <p style="font-size:17px; font-family:GothamRoundedBold;">Branding • Product Dev • Web Dev</p>
    </div> 
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.worklongdiv{
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 120px;
    max-height:auto
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;  
 }  

.worklongdiv:hover img {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.worklongdiv:hover .work-text-content-long {
    opacity: 1; 
}

.worklongdiv img {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}

.worklongdiv img,
.work-text-content-long {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
}

.work-text-content-long {
    height:100px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    left: 0;
    top: 25%;
    right: 0%;
    left:101px;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `;` in one of your CSS rules.

```
.worklongdiv{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 120px;
  max-height:auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: This still has the same effect?

Comment: I mis-read your code. Please try to do a better job of formatting the code with proper indentation. I updated the solution - you were missing a semicolon, resulting in `position:relative` not being applied.